# Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...) in enzyme and hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, act

I have written this component. it fetchs data using hooks and state. Once it is fetched the loading state is changed to false and show the sidebar.

I faced a problem with Jest and Enzyme, as it does throw a warning for Act in my unit test. once I add the act to my jest and enzyme the test is failed!

```js
// @flow
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';
import fetchData from '../apiWrappers/fetchData';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const newData = await fetchData();
        setData(newData);
        setLoading(false);
      }
      catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {!loading
        ? <Sidebar />
        : <span>Loading List</span>}
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

And, I have added a test like this which works perfectly.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import fetchData from '../apiWrappers/fetchData';
import data from '../data/data.json';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('../apiWrappers/fetchData');

const getData = Promise.resolve(data);
fetchData.mockReturnValue(getData);

describe('<App/> Rendering using enzyme', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchData.mockClear();
  });

  test('After loading', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find('span').at(0).text()).toEqual('Loading List');

    const d = await fetchData();
    expect(d).toHaveLength(data.length);

    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('span').exists()).toEqual(false);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

So, I got a warning:

```
Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
```

I did resolve the warning like this using { act } react-dom/test-utils.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import fetchData from '../apiWrappers/fetchData';
import data from '../data/data.json';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('../apiWrappers/fetchData');

const getData = Promise.resolve(data);
fetchData.mockReturnValue(getData);

describe('<App/> Rendering using enzyme', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchData.mockClear();
  });

  test('After loading', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<App />);
      expect(wrapper.find('span').at(0).text()).toEqual('Loading List');

      const d = await fetchData();
      expect(d).toHaveLength(data.length);

      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.find('span').exists()).toEqual(false);
      expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

But, then my test is failed.

```
<App/> Rendering using enzyme › After loading

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: false
Received: true

  35 | 
  36 |       wrapper.update();
> 37 |       expect(wrapper.find('span').exists()).toEqual(false);
```

Does anybody know why it fails? Thanks!

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.3",
```

Comment: Wow, nice question with those Run code snippets in there! Upvote just for that!

Answer (score 20):

This issue is not new at all. You can read the full discussion here: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2073.

To sum up, currently in order to fix `act` warning, you have to wait a bit before update your wrapper as following:

```js
const waitForComponentToPaint = async (wrapper) => {
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
    wrapper.update();
  });
};

test('After loading', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.find('span').at(0).text()).toEqual('Loading List');
  
  // before the state updated
  await waitForComponentToPaint(wrapper);
  // after the state updated

  expect(wrapper.find('span').exists()).toEqual(false);
  expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I had read the link actually. And, I've just tried your code. But, I get the same warning even after using code. The only way to bypass it is to  wrap my whole test in an act like this. `test.only('After loading', async () => { await act(async () => { /* the actual test */ });});` But that is too much!!
I am using `useEffect` in my `<App />`, that might be an issue. I have seen this comment https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2073, but it is complex to implement it for me. Do you have any other suggestions to do it without wrap every single of my test?

Comment: Try to increase the timeout `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 20));` to check if it would help?

Comment: Or you can also try to wrap above code in `act()` I guess

Comment: I have tried and increased the time even to 100, but still, get the warning. If I wrap the above code in the act, I will get another warning. 

The only way it works so far is like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-act-warning-with-enzyme?file=src/App.test.js

But, I do not want to do like that for every single test, it is kind of too much and a little messy. Do you know anyway I can simplify it ? :)

Comment: I don't think we necessarily use `wait-for-expect` to make it work :) do you have a minimal code (could be a small repo) which can re-produce the the issue?

Comment: No I do not have smaller repo :(, I have tried a lot without `wait-for-expect` but I could not make it.

Comment: This just saved my day! Thanks

Comment: this causes the test to hang and evenutally fail with `: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`

Answer (score 3):

You should not wrap your whole test in `act`, just the part that will cause `state` of your component to update.

Something like the below should solve your problem.

```
 test('After loading', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    });

    expect(wrapper.find('span').at(0).text()).toEqual('Loading List');

    
    const d = await fetchData();
    expect(d).toHaveLength(data.length);

    await act(async () => {
      wrapper.update();
    })
    expect(wrapper.find('span').exists()).toEqual(false);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```